# Kitty run command in current shell via action

Tags: kitty

Is it possible to run a command in the currently open shell via an action using the [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) terminal emulator?

For example when defining hyperlink actions:

```
protocol file
mime inode/directory
action [RUN SHELL ACTION] cd ${FILE_PATH}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, I use these blocks:

```
# Opens file in vim in current terminal when clicked.
protocol file
mime text/*
#action launch --type=overlay $EDITOR $FILE_PATH
action send_text normal,application vi "${FILE_PATH}"\r

# Cd to directory and ls in current terminal when directory is clicked
protocol file
mime inode/directory
action send_text normal,application cd "${FILE_PATH}" && ls \r
```